# Есть и жрать

Tags: употребление-слов

По отношению к человеку мне всегда говорим, что он ест. По отношению к животному говорим, что оно ест, но при этом животное может кого-то пожирать. Точно также, например, огонь пожара именно пожирает гектары леса, а автомобиль много бензина именно жрет.
При этом выражение "жрать, пожирать" по отношению к человеку является уничижительным, но далеко не всегда обозначает количество поедаемой пищи.
И все-таки где грань между словами "есть" и "жрать" и почему в разных вариантах употребляются то то, то другое выражение?

Answer (score 2):

Глаголы "есть и жрать" относятся к общеславянским словам индоевропейского характера и   отмечаются в русском языке с 11 века в формах жьрьти и ѣсти.

Когда-то слово "жрать", сейчас просторечно-грубое, имело нейтральный характер, но затем стилевая характеристика  двух глаголов стала различаться. В качестве причины можно указать тот факт, что старшее значение глагола "жрать" - это "глотать пищу", а ближайшими его родственниками  являются   "горло" и "жерло" (вулкана). Неудивительно, что на определенном этапе слову "жрать" было приписано значение не просто глотать пищу, а глотать ее быстро и жадно (очевидно, не пережевывая  тщательно).

То же самое можно сказать о диких  животных, глотающих куски мясо, а затем в переносном смысле обо всем, что быстро глотается/поглощается.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "жрать"  имеет вульгарно-просторечный характер по отношению к человеку. По отношению к животным он имеет разг. оттенок и не является грубым.Глагол же " пожирать"имеет имеет пом.сниж. лишь по отношению к человеку.Ср.,например: ПОЖИРАТЬ, 1.
*Есть, поедать с жадностью (о животных; **разг.-сниж. о человеке**). Мошки пожирали геологов. П. съестные припасы. П. в спешке* В других значениях этот глагол имеет или разг.оттенок или нейтр.и не имеет негативной окраски. Ср.: 2. *Разг*.
Быстро, с жадностью и интересом прочитывать (книги, газеты, журналы и т.п.). П. приключенческие романы. П. одну газету за другой.
3. ***Разг.***
Поглощать, требовать для себя что-л. в больших количествах. Всё время пожирает учёба. Машина пожирает много бензина. П. глазами или взглядом
(страстно, жадно, с напряжением, вниманием всматриваться в кого-, что-л.).
4.
Уничтожать, сжигая, поглощая. П. прямо на глазах. Пламя с хрустом пожирает поленья. [] безл. Огнём пожирает молодой лес.
5.
Захватывать целиком (о чувствах). Ненависть пожирает мою душу. Её пожирало любопытство. Пожираемый страстью, сомнениями, муками, жаждой знания. С пожирающим любопытством, вниманием и т.п. Исходя из этого,можно сказать: машина ест/жрет много бензина.Ошибкой не будет ни тот, ни другой вариант.